# None of the NLog AspNetRequest layour renderers are working for ASP.NET 4.6 web forms app

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

I am not getting any values for the AspNetRequest layout renderers in an ASP.NET 4.6.2 Framework Web Forms app.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNetRequest-layout-renderer

All three of the following and several others that I have tried are all empty strings. Is there some global switch I need to enable within NLog to get these to work?

```
dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@VisitedPage", "${aspnet-request-host}"));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@PageURL", "${aspnet-appbasepath}"));
dbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo("@ReferrerURL", "${aspnet-request:header=Referer}"));
```

Comment: When needing to do troubleshooting, then [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging is a good place to start. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting - Notice NLog v5 requires you to explicit register [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web#release-body-tab)-extension.

Comment: I just registered NLog.Web in the system.webserver section of the web.config and that made no difference.

Comment: When configuration from code, then you need to do the registration from code. Ex. `LogManager.Setup().RegisterNLogWeb()` before starting to build the `dbTarget`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API

Comment: @RolfKristensen -- this worked and is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLog v5 no longer automatically scan and [load extension assemblies](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlog-extensions-assemblies-will-not-load-automatically). This means NLog.Web-LayoutRenderers are not available by default.

Instead one have manually register [NLog.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web) extensions. This can be done in NLog.config:

```xml
<extensions>
   <add assembly="NLog.Web" />
</extensions>
```

Or it can also be done from code (before starting to build `dbTarget`):

```cs
LogManager.Setup().RegisterNLogWeb()
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API